# Transform your site?

Tags: traducción

¿Cómo se dice "Transform your site" en Español?  Pienso es

> Convertirse su sito

pero no se si es correcto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, sin contexto alguno es difícil dar la mejor traducción. Así, a simple vista pareciera un anuncio publicitario relacionado con sitios de Internet (también llamados sitios web). Y en efecto tu traducción no es correcta.

> Convertirse

es reflexivo, es decir la acción de convertir recae en el hablante, y ninguna persona creo, estaría interesada en convertirse en un sitio. La traducción más adecuada de este uso del verbo `convertir` me parece que seria `become`.

Lo adecuado en este caso sería irnos por la opción más obvia y literal:

> Transforma tu sitio.

o bien:

> Transforme su sitio.

Si quieres que sea más formal.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to add some context.

I assume you are talking about a web site. In that case, this would work in most cases:

> Transforme su sitio web.

Depending on context, if the trasformation is towards something "newer", it could be better to say:

> Renueve su sitio web.

Because "renovar" (renew, update) is a form of transformation and is supposed to be to a better state.

Excuse my English.